# Firebug and Chrome rendering two body tags

Tags: themes, filters

I have a curly problem I've been working on for some time. At first it appears as if the get_body_class() function was broken but after I removed it from the template the issue persists.

```
<html class="js firefox">
<head>
<body>
 <body>
  <div class="top_div">
  <div id="page" class="hfeed site logo">
  <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
  <div class="footer_wrapper">
</body>
```

Yet when I view the same via page source I see only one body tag.

I am using the latest version of Wordpress and all plugins are up to date.

Things I have tried to resolve the issue:

- Disabling all plugins
- Changing to default theme
- Replacing the wp-admin folder
- Forcing UTF-8 without BOM encoding on all PHP files

Note that if I completely remove the body tag from the header.php file I only see a single body tag in Firebug and in page source I see the following:

[image: pagesource screenshot]

Comment: [1] If you have any cacheing plugin, sometimes deactivating them won't solve the issue - you will need to clear the cache before deactivating them. [2] Have you checked on other person's PC/Browser. [3] Have you checked your site using [any proxy server](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+proxy+server)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have checked from multiple browsers and machines both PC and Mac and they are all rendering with issue above. I have no caching plugin installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by commenting out the first body tag and placing a second body tag below like this:

```
<!--

<body>

-->
<body <?php body_class( $class ); ?>>
```

Now the site is working correctly. However the strange character is still appearing in the first body tag.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: That's good but have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22255197/4813913

Comment: I took a look at it. My wp-config.php was not infected. So I think this is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'strange' character is one that exists outside of the standard character set. Some browsers and text editors will display this as a small square or rectangle, some may display a small dot, some may not display it at all.

It could have crept in through a copy and paste, but that's just a guess.

If commenting the  tag out and adding a fresh one in resolves the problem then why not delete it altogether?

As to why this would cause two  tags I can only guess that the browser is trying to be clever and correcting the code as it is seeing a page with a  and not  so assumes it should add one in (every web page needs a ). You end up seeing two s because the browser doesn't know to render the extra random character.

You could test this theory maybe by trying the site in an older, less intelligent browser (I'm thinking IE8 or below) and seeing what happens.

Comment: When I deleted it all together something in the Wordpress core was writing it the body tag with the ascii character. This is why I resorted to commenting out the first one and placing a second tag with the body_class function in place.